# Как в CommerceML2 при обмене заказом 1С - Сайт, отправить значение Действии Товара?

Tags: php, 1с

При обмене заказами в 1с - сайт, заказы попадают в раздел Заказы клиентов, при открытии заказа вкладка Действие стоит К обеспечению, как при отправке с сайта сделать так чтобы заказы с сайта были К отгрузке. Ибо приходится внутри заказа, возле каждого товара руками менять с обеспечения на отгрузку. Благодарю!

Comment: Обмен происходит с помощью какого-то подключенного модуля?

Comment: Обмен происходит стандартными средствами 1с УТ, в разделе НСИ - Обмен сайтом

Comment: Настроек никаких нет?